# Retrieve data based on boolean logic

Tags: python, database, abstract-syntax-tree, boolean-expression

I'll get right to my question. I have an API that gives me a number of items based on a category I input. I can only request one category per API call. Now I want to retrieve a number of items using a boolean expression using AND and OR. So for example
(HOUSE AND PLANT) OR ANIMAL
My idea was to create an binary AST and then from that AST a boolean expression. This works but i want to minimize API calls. So the next step was to create a list based on the calling order and then only use one calls for AND statements and then filter the other.

```py
OR ANIMAL <- API CALL
  AND HOUSE <- API CALL
    PLANT
```

I can't get a good idea on how to create that list. So to know what calls i need and then filter later. Any other approaches would help aswell.